# Hibernate with use of 2 foreign keys pointing to the same object causing serialization issues

Tags: java, json, hibernate

I have a class `Post` which has two fields which are foreign keys to the `Post` object. All worked fine while I used only one of them, when I added another, it resulted in strange `infinite loop` like looking JSON.

My entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Posts", catalog = "StackOverflow")

public class Post {
    private Integer Id, PostTypeId, ParentId, AcceptedAnswerId, Score, ViewCount, OwnerUserId, LastEditorUserId, AnswerCount,
            CommentCount, FavoriteCount;
    private String Body, Title, Tags;
    private Date CreationDate, LastEditDate, LastActivityDate;
    private Post parentPost;
    private Post acceptedAnswer;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "Id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "PostTypeId")
    public Integer getPostTypeId() {
        return PostTypeId;
    }

    public void setPostTypeId(Integer postTypeId) {
        PostTypeId = postTypeId;
    }

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ParentId", referencedColumnName = "Id")
    public Post getParentPost(){
        return parentPost;
    }

    public void setParentPost(Post parentPost) {
        this.parentPost = parentPost;
    }
    /*@Column(name = "ParentId")
    public Integer getParentId() {
        return ParentId;
    }

    public void setParentId(Integer parentId) {
        ParentId = parentId;
    }*/



    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "AcceptedAnswerId", referencedColumnName = "Id")
    public Post getAcceptedAnswer(){
        return acceptedAnswer;
    }

    public void setAcceptedAnswer(Post acceptedAnswer) {
        this.acceptedAnswer = acceptedAnswer;
    }
    /*@Column(name = "AcceptedAnswerId")
    public Integer getAcceptedAnswerId() {
        return AcceptedAnswerId;
    }

    public void setAcceptedAnswerId(Integer acceptedAnswerId) {
        AcceptedAnswerId = acceptedAnswerId;
    }*/

    @Column(name = "Score")
    public Integer getScore() {
        return Score;
    }

    public void setScore(Integer score) {
        Score = score;
    }
    @Column(name = "ViewCount")
    public Integer getViewCount() {
        return ViewCount;
    }

    public void setViewCount(Integer viewCount) {
        ViewCount = viewCount;
    }
    @Column(name = "OwnerUserId")
    public Integer getOwnerUserId() {
        return OwnerUserId;
    }

    public void setOwnerUserId(Integer ownerUserId) {
        OwnerUserId = ownerUserId;
    }
    @Column(name = "LastEditorUserId")
    public Integer getLastEditorUserId() {
        return LastEditorUserId;
    }

    public void setLastEditorUserId(Integer lastEditorUserId) {
        LastEditorUserId = lastEditorUserId;
    }
    @Column(name = "AnswerCount")
    public Integer getAnswerCount() {
        return AnswerCount;
    }

    public void setAnswerCount(Integer answerCount) {
        AnswerCount = answerCount;
    }
    @Column(name = "CommentCount")
    public Integer getCommentCount() {
        return CommentCount;
    }

    public void setCommentCount(Integer commentCount) {
        CommentCount = commentCount;
    }
    @Column(name = "FavoriteCount")
    public Integer getFavoriteCount() {
        return FavoriteCount;
    }

    public void setFavoriteCount(Integer favoriteCount) {
        FavoriteCount = favoriteCount;
    }
    @Column(name = "Body")
    public String getBody() {
        return Body;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        Body = body;
    }
    @Column(name = "Title")
    public String getTitle() {
        return Title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        Title = title;
    }
    @Column(name = "Tags")
    public String getTags() {
        return Tags;
    }

    public void setTags(String tags) {
        Tags = tags;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "CreationDate")
    public Date getCreationDate() {
        return CreationDate;
    }

    public void setCreationDate(Date creationDate) {
        CreationDate = creationDate;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "LastEditDate")
    public Date getLastEditDate() {
        return LastEditDate;
    }

    public void setLastEditDate(Date lastEditDate) {
        LastEditDate = lastEditDate;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "LastActivityDate")
    public Date getLastActivityDate() {
        return LastActivityDate;
    }

    public void setLastActivityDate(Date lastActivityDate) {
        LastActivityDate = lastActivityDate;
    }

}
```

Part of the JSON result:

```
{"parentPost":null,"acceptedAnswer":{"parentPost":{"parentPost":null,"acceptedAnswer":{"parentPost":{"parentPost":null,"acceptedAnswer":{"parentPost":{"parentPost":null,"acceptedAnswer":{"parentPost":{"parentPost":null,"acceptedAnswer":{"parentPost":{"parentPost":null,"acceptedAnswer":{"parentPost":{"parentPost":null,"acceptedAnswer":{"parentPost":{"parentPost":null,"acceptedAnswer":{"parentPost":{"parentPost":null,"acceptedAnswer":{"parentPost":{"parentPost":null,"acceptedAnswer":{"parentPost":{"parentPost":null,"acceptedAnswer":{"parentPost":{"parentPost":null,"acceptedAnswer":{"parentPost":{"parentPost":null,"acceptedAnswer":{"parentPost":{"parentPost":null,"acceptedAnswer":{"parentPost":{"parentPost":null,"acceptedAnswer":{"parentPost":{"parentPost":null,"acceptedAnswer":{"parentPost":{"parentPost":null,"acceptedAnswer":{"parentPost":{"parentPost":null,"acceptedAnswer":{"parentPost":{"parentPost":null,"acceptedAnswer":{"parentPost":{"parentPost":null,"acceptedAnswer":{"parentPost":
```

This obviously causes my IDE to not respond.

Part of the exception I was able to get:

```
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:656)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like one of your `Post` objects has a `parentPost` that in its turn has a reference back to the `Post` object through an `aceptedAnswer` property.

In this situation when the marshaller does its job it has no point to stop, because it will go back and forth in infinite loop between these two objects.

It really depends on the what you want to achive, but making the reference to a Parent post  transparent for the marshaller looks like the most natural way to go because usually you consider a question first and then looking for the answer. However if you for instance starting from an answer and then see what was the original question, you may want to make acceptedAnswer transient instead.

Anyway the way to do it would depend on what you use as a marshaller. For Jackson for instance you would consider use of

[@JsonIgnore](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.2/index.html?com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html)
or 
[@JsonIgnoreProperties](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html)

[Here](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-properties-on-serialization) some examples how it is used.

Hope that helps

Comment: I had this fixed already by the `@JsonIgnore` and had no time yet to post it here, so I am glad you figured out and you did that. Thank you +1